# NumPy where condition to get cells with max(R,G,B) > a threshold

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to make a mask that has ones corresponding to certain cells in an image. These cells should have at least one of their RGB color values greater than a threshold. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
B = image[0:h,0:w,0].astype(int)
G = image[0:h,0:w,1].astype(int)
R = image[0:h,0:w,2].astype(int)
mask = np.zeros((h,w))

mask[np.where( max(R,G,B) > threshold )] = 1
```

This gives an error:

> ValueError occurred
>     Message=The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is a 3D array `(h, w, 3)`, you can get `max(R, G, B)` by simply taking the maximum of the last axis:

```
np.max(image, axis=-1)
```

Compare the returned value with `threshold` and you get a `bool` array. Cast that to `int` to get a mask of zeroes and ones:

```
mask = (np.max(image, axis=-1) > threshold).astype(int)
```